# Why does "Date d = new Date();" return an error?

Tags: android, date, time

This has probably been asked and answered a million times, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.  Upon starting an activity in an android app, I want to display the current date and time.  From what I understand the date part can be done simply with the following:

```
Date d = new Date();  
d.getTime();  
CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy", d.getTime());  

TextView date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dateText);  
date.setText(s);  

TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeText);  
time.setText(s);
```

In eclipse it gives me an error and says that the constructor date is undefined.  I chose the auto fix option and it added a 0 as a parameter in the Date constructor.  This produced a date, but the date is Dec. 31, 1969.  What am I missing here?

This is probably trivial, but I'm still new to this stuff.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I'd prefer http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis() instead of creating a big ugly Date object if you're not going to use it again.

Answer (score 38):

You are probably using `java.sql.Date`. You want to be using `java.util.Date`.

Comment: This is indeed probably why the compiler is complaining about requiring a parameter to the date constructor.

Comment: Changing to java.util.Date worked.  I need to re-format the date so I may post again if I can't get that figured out pretty quick.  Thanks for your help

Comment: No worries. This page shows the date formats you can use ... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html - Also, pressing the 'tick' next to my block would be nice. :)

Comment: @Brandon Englert: If this was the correct answer, don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (the tick) :)

Answer (score 0):

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html for constructor Date(long time):

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Instead, take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

Answer (score 0):

Import **java.util.Date** and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Is there any much deference between yours answer and @musaul 's answer?

Comment: Nope and why will there be? After all that's the correct answer, and I've quite a few times faced this same situation which Brandon did and the solution I've given worked for me. So, I posted my reply.